# Show Desktop.scf wont run using subprocess in windows 7

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Why is this script running in windows xp, but not working in windows 7?

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:/showdesktop.scf'],shell=True)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does `c:\showdesktop.scf` actually exist on the Windows 7 machine?  Where did it come from?  What happens if you run it directly rather than via Python?

Comment: yes its existing. It minimize all the application when I double click it.
[Shell]
Command=2
IconFile=explorer.exe,3
[Taskbar]
Command=ToggleDesktop

Comment: It might be worth trying a backslash instead of a forward slash.  Windows only accepts forward slashes in path names some of the time.

Comment: I've done that already with no success, when I try to run other files like .txt or .exe in the same directory it works. Actually Im using this very often in windows xp, its working great but when i tried it in windows 7 nothing happen.